# NoReverseMatch in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django

I know there are lot of questions already ask about this error but for some reason none of them work for me.

**What i am trying to do?**

I am trying to pass a variable from view `ActivateAccount` to another view `result` upon email confirmation.

**What is the problem?**

I am doing everything right according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/) and previously posted question about the same error but i still get this error:

```
Reverse for 'result' with keyword arguments '{'test': 'Email confirmed successfully!'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<test>[\\w-]+)/$']
```

**caller view.py:**

```
def ActivateAccount(request, uidb64, token):

test = ''
if uidb64 is not None and token is not None:
   ...
   test = "Email confirmed successfully!"

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('result', kwargs={'test': test}))
```

**urls.py:**

```
 url(r'^(?P<test>[\w-]+)/$', views.result, name='result')
```

**receiver view.py:**

```
def result(request, test=None, *args, **kargs):
data = {'msg': test}
return JsonResponse(data) // this return the result to ajax 'GET'
```

And i would also like to know why is there double backslash `\\` in the regex (`[\\w-]`) instead of single in the error. As in my url i have a single `\` (`[\w-]`).

thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't think you understand what `[\w-]+` means. Your expression only matches `Email`, the rest of the string is ignored which is why it cannot find a match.  Change your regular expression to `^[\w\s!]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 url(r'^(?P<test>[a-zA-Z!\s]+)/$', views.result, name='result')
```

use this urlpattern

Comment: Still the same error and why does it always adds one more  backslash ? `Reverse for 'result' with keyword arguments '{'test': 'Email confirmed successfully!'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<test>[a-zA-Z\\s]+)/$']`

Comment: remove the ! from the message and try once again

Comment: or just add it in regex `[a-zA-Z!\s]+`

Comment: yeah you can add the ! in the regexx as @Gahan said

Comment: A more compact representation would be `[\w\s!]+`

Comment: okay that fixed it but that still doesn't explain why does django add double backslash in the error ?

Comment: and is it possible to hide the argument in the browser url ?

Comment: no as your url is taking the argument you cannot hide it

Comment: @Exprator `[a-zA-Z\s]+` to `[a-zA-Z!\s]+`